# how to find installed path for ruby and bundle on ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, bundle

I installed ruby 1.9.3 on ubuntu 10.04 server. There is problem with capistrano to find the bundle. How to find the path for the ruby dir and where is bundle located? There are /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125 and /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global. There are bundles in multiple subdirs under /.rvm/.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`which bundle` to find where bundler binary is located

If you need to run Capistrano in the context of current bundle, run `bundle exec cap`

Comment: `which` is a very useful command! Learned something new today =)

Comment: it is not in my path, but circle ci is able to find it, how can I guess where it is ?